# Unable to write WHERE condition for a JSON array field with array values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have a JSON datatype with array values in a MySQL database as highlighted in the picture below:

[image]

I want to compare multiple values with this `category` field, Ex: `["49","27"]`.

How to write a MySQL query for this?

I tried this query:

```
SELECT l.*, pc.name as cat_name,u.name as uname
FROM listing l
LEFT OUTER JOIN package_purchased_history ph ON ph.user_id = l.user_id AND ph.expired_date >= 1656095400 AND ph.purchase_date <= 1656095400
LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON u.id = l.user_id
INNER JOIN category pc ON JSON_SEARCH(l.categories, 'one', pc.id) AND pc.parent = 26
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(l.categories,'["49"]','$[0]') IS NOT NULL
AND l.status = 'active'
GROUP BY l.id
```

Unfortunately it is not working, so please suggest me the a better approach.

Comment: Please spend some time writing a good, polished and understandable post. It will help others help you effectively.

Comment: `JSON_CONTAINS(l.categories, '[49]', '$')`

Comment: The JSON data to be found in the array is string (`["49","27"]`) whereas you search for numeric value in your code (`[49]`) which won't be found. Search for string value `["49"]`...

Answer (score 1):

`$[0]` is the first element of the array, not the whole array. So you're testing whether an array is contained in a single number, not whether the array is contained in the array.

The whole array is `$`, since that refers to the top-level element of the JSON value. But you don't need to specify the path when you're searching the whole value.

```
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(l.categories, '[49]')
```

You don't need `IS NOT NULL` there, since `JSON_CONTAINS()` returns a boolean. The value will never be `NULL` unless `l.categories` is `NULL`.